# Avoid view only mode after creating record using lightning:recordForm (enforce always new record creation mode)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I would like to use the component `lightning:recordForm` to simplify the process for creating always a new record, however, after the record is successfully created and the user is redirected to main page, after clicking on the component's button to create a new record, it appears as view mode, showing the values related to the previous record adding the capacity to edit it, however what I want is to create a new one..

```
<lightning:recordForm
        objectApiName="{!v.objectApiName}"
        fields="{!v.fields}"
        recordTypeId = "{!v.recordTypeId}"
        mode="edit"
        onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
        oncancel="{!c.closeModel}"
        columns="1"
/>
```

I tried to reset the recordId attribute, enforce the mode attribute..but nothing,

do you know how can I do this?

Thanks!